# Universal Analytics - Track demographic data on server side

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am using Staccato gem to fire [pageview events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) from server side.

While on client side enabling demographic data tracking is easily added by using

```
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
```

How can I add similar support to server side tracking?

Comment: not yet, still haven't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you really need it? Demographics is collecting info about the user by Google already knowing stuff about the visitor. If I visit your site, Google get a page view for this, and Google know that it's me because of cookies and session data. It will know my gender, age and interests from Google+, Youtube and such (Only Google know for sure).

Even if you know something about the user on the server side, I'm having a hard time believing that you could transfer that knowledge to Google. If you say that this user is example@gmail.com on Youtube, Google has no way of knowing if this is true.

If you have gender and age info, you could upload this with the measurement protocol though.

Comment: My purpose is to track and segment outgoing traffic.
Redirect is done on the server side and i'm using existing google client id to track this event as 'pageview'